# Azure, WCF services and restricting part of the interface?

Tags: wcf, azure, service, interface

I could not find a direct answer to this. Basically I have services MainService and SubService. The idea is that the Client software calls some methods in the MainService, but SubService calls another part of the service in MainService.

I am deploying to Azure and I want to have two separate interfaces in MainService, one for client and one for SubService and I don't want Client service to have any chance of access to the interface the SubService uses.

Given that I am new to WCF services, I am not sure how to approach this. Do I need multiple web roles for different interfaces that access the same database and handle concurrency issues etc. there, or can I somehow include multiple interfaces but restrict the availability by, for example, certificates. I am not exactly sure on Azure firewall rules, but if the interface in MainService that is meant for the SubService could be mapped to a separate port that would be behind a firewall rule, that would also be a viable solution.

tl;dr: Need two separate interfaces in a WCF service, one for client software (open for outer world), one for a sub-system service. Both services are to be run in Azure. What are my options?

Comment: I believe you can make your SubService require authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard WCF authorization and authentication.  For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647503.aspx

If you wanted to use Azure Service Bus with relay messaging, you could use some of the authentication and authorization provided by Service Bus.  But, I'm not sure if there's any extra value there compared to just hosting your WCF in a web role (you'd have to do that in either case, but the access to the service would be decoupled from the clients via Service Bus).